# How to hook something before saving in Rails Devise::RegistrationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I wanna do something before `User` is saved in `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`.

I can use callback methods like `before_save`, but it does too many things because I want it only in RegistrationsController.

See the code below:
(This is `Devise::RegistrationsController#create`)

```
def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.do_something_i_want # <= HERE

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
end
```

It seems the only way to do this is copy & paste the `create` method of devise into `Users::RegistrationsController`.

Can I do this more easily?

Comment: What about `after_initialize`?

Comment: maybe if `do_something_i_want` was more explanatory we could be of more assistance but since the resource yield occurs after save your best bet (as others have mentioned) is to override the action.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple callbacks available in rails. You can check them [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html). In your case below will work fine. To override controller you need to make multiple changes.

```
before_create :do_something

before_save :do_something, on: :create

after_validation :do_something, on: :create
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want these `do_something` only in specific controllers.

Comment: > To override controller you need to make multiple changes.
So you say the way I wrote in the question is the best way to satisfy my purpose accurately?

Comment: If you need method in specific controller then you have to override device controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could override create method and

```
def create
  super.create do |res|
    res.do_something_i_want
  end
end
```

Due to: yield resource if block_given? 
However it is one line after the one you need. (after save)

I don't like callbacks after_save/before save because you can end up adding too match logic there with little control. Also there could be cases where you dont want to call your callbacks.

Comment: Thanks but this seems inserted into the `yield`, which is located after save?

Comment: I want  do_something before saving.

Comment: Then your best bet is customizing your controller